# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority-While deploying Kubeflow

Tags: single-sign-on, kubeflow

I have been trying to integrate google sso with our dev instance. When we deployed the changes, we are facing this issue
`level=error msg="OIDC provider setup failed, retrying in 10 seconds: Get \":instance-url/.well-known/openid-configuration\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`.

We tried using the image that was mentioned in one of the stack overflow links for the oidc service, that doesn't seem to work either.

The image we used `gcr.io/arrikto/kubeflow/oidc-authservice:2cb5bf6`

Anyone who faced similar issues and you had resolved it, kindly give-in your inputs. would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an ssl certificate issue related to the error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

1. Make sure the type of your ssl certificate.
2. In some cases, self-signed SSL certificates cannot be supported in this scenario. You can easily obtain a free, non-signed certificate instead if it's only for a test environment.

Additionally, I have tried the image you provided here gcr.io/arrikto/kubeflow/oidc-authservice:2cb5bf6, it requires an additional terms of service agreement for initial access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is likely because you are using the self-signed certificate of your cluster. Google will only trust certificates that were signed by a public Certificate Authority (CA).
You can use something like `certbot` to get a Let's Encrypt certificate (signed by the Let's Encrypt public CA) for the domain you're using, for use with OIDC.

This will be the case regardless of which image you use. The image will not provide you a public CA signed certificate - you need to provide it.